# How to Run DailyMotion Video in Windows Store App?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I want to run dailymotion videos in my store app but iam getting this problem "uri string is too long " any solution please or can you give me the link from where i can see the whole tutorial to play dailymotion video

**XAML code:**

```
Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"> <MediaElement x:Name="Mediaplayer" Width="450" Height="250" Stretch="Fill" AutoPlay="True"/> </Grid>
```

**cs Code:**

```
     protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)    {
                base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
                if (e.Parameter == null) return;
               // var clickedItem = e.Parameter.ToString();
               // var index = int.Parse(clickedItem);
                var url = "http://www.dailymotion.com/musicworld";

             using (var client = new HttpClient())
             {
                 var videodata = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                 // _videos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VideoApi.RootObject>(videodata);
                 Mediaplayer.Source=new Uri(videodata);
             } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the whole contents of the page as a Uri to the Media Player. Not only is this too long to be a Uri (you're passing 118K+) which is the error you received but it's not a Uri.

DailyMotion have a number of APIs available for extracting the information you seek. See https://developer.dailymotion.com/. Specifically, look at the Data API and other documentation on their developer site.